# Audio Driver for Lenovo G500 DOLBY ADVANCED AUDIO v2

Tags: drivers, sound

My laptop is Lenovo G500. 
Processor i5. 500GB HDD and 4GB RAM.
When I used to have Windows, I could actually feel the Dolby sound. But after Ubuntu, the volume is already seems to b low or say not a High Definition sound and the Dolby feel is not coming.

Please tell me how can I get a better sound quality and more volumed sound
(Volume is already 100%, but in Windows it used to give more volume)

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have the Dolby Advanced Audio v2 in my Lenovo laptop. I understand that you do not have the Dolby 'feel' because louder music tends to 'feel' of being of better quality, of course there is some difference that it makes, but I have the idea not much.

You can increase the volume in the audio settings with allowing volume to go beyond 100% then it amplifies up to 150% I think. You click on the speaker icon in the bar and then click sound settings and then you'll see where you can enable the volume-increase

Comment: Increasing sound volume doesnot make it dolby advanced sound

Answer (score 0):

You can probably install an app called EasyEffects. It's an app that allows you to customize your audio settings such as equalizer and reverb, it'll probably will fix your audio issue and make it (hopefully) more High Definition. I've used it for a week now and it does make some diffrence in terms of the sound quality.

And for the app installation, you can install EasyEffects through flatpak.